# Moment generating function of Random Sums

Tags: statistics, random-variables, moment-generating-functions

I am unsure of a particular step in the supplied solution of this problem.

Problem:

We are given $X_{i}$, for i = 1,..., n, is a sequence of iid Geometric Random Variables.

N ~ Geometric(p), and N is independent of all the $X_{i}$'s

$S_{N} = \sum^{N}_{i=1}Xi$.

What is the MGF of $S_{N}$?

My working:

Let $Y = S_{N}$

Know that $M_{X}(t) = \frac{pe^{t}}{1-qe^{t}}$ (from an earlier part of this problem).
So the conditional MGF of the random sum is $M_{Y|N}(t|N) = [M_{X}(t)]^{N} = [\frac{pe^{t}}{1-qe^{t}}]^{N}$

Next, MGF of Y, $M_{Y}(t) = E[M_{Y|N}(t|N)] = E[(\frac{pe^{t}}{1-qe^{t}})^{N}]$

I am able to show up till this part, so everything above is fine. The next step is to perform this:

$E[(\frac{pe^{t}}{1-qe^{t}})^{N}] = \frac{p.\frac{pe^{t}}{1-qe^{t}}}{1-q.\frac{pe^{t}}{1-qe^{t}}} $

I don't understand  why the expression for the denominator takes that form if we are bringing it up by power of N. Can someone kindly explain the reasoning for it please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $N\sim\text{Geometric}(p)$, we wish to compute $\mathbb E[\gamma^N]$ for $\gamma:=\frac{pe^t}{1-qe^t}$. Now, since $\left|p\frac{qe^t}{1-qe^t}\right|$$<1$ for $t<-\log (q(1+p))$, observe that the infinite sum of a geometric series justifies
$$\mathbb E[\gamma^N]=\sum\limits_{j=1}^{\infty}\gamma^j(1-p)^{j-1}p=\frac{p}{1-p}\sum\limits_{j=1}^{\infty}(\gamma(1-p))^j=\frac{p}{1-p}\frac{\gamma(1-p)}{1-\gamma(1-p)} = \frac{p\gamma}{1-q\gamma}.$$

That is,

> $$\mathbb E\Big[\Big(\frac{pe^t}{1-qe^t}\Big)^N\Big] = \frac{p\frac{pe^t}{1-qe^t}}{1-q\frac{pe^t}{1-qe^t}}$$

Comment: Thank you ki3i, this is very very clear. Just to check also - on the numerator for your above expression between the absolute bars, did you mean to type p.pe^t instead of p.qe^t?

Comment: @SanjouOdawali, Notice that, for $t<-\log q$, $$1>\Big| p\frac{qe^t}{1-qe^t}\Big|=\Big|q\frac{pe^t}{1-qe^t}\Big|=\Big|q\gamma\Big|=\Big| \gamma (1-p)\Big|,$$ which is why we can apply the infinite sum of the geometric series.

Comment: Thank you ki3i, I get it now - you need that to show that the term is bounded between (-1,1) so the infinite geo sum can be used.

Comment: @SanjouOdawali, yes, that's correct.

Comment: It isn't true that $\left|p\frac{qe^t}{1-qe^t}\right|<1$ whenever $t<-\log q$. This can be seen from the fact that $t<-\log q\iff qe^t<1$, and when $qe^t$ is close to 1, $\left|p\frac{qe^t}{1-qe^t}\right|$ explodes.

Rather, one can show, by simply rearranging the inequality, that given $t<-\log q$, we have $$\left|p\frac{qe^t}{1-qe^t}\right|<1 \iff t<-\log (q(p+1))$$

Comment: @toe-pose yes, you are quite right, thanks.